# Implementing a Routing system for my Views (ExtJS)

Tags: extjs, view, extjs5

I want to implement a route for my basic view in ExtJS so that when display it (on a button click) the URL changes and when i want to return back to the initial view it works by displaying the right view.

Giving my view class :

```
Ext.define('Traccar.view.newDashboard', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.newDashboard',
    id: 'geoAfricaDashboard',

routes : {
        'dashboard' : ''

     },

    layout: {
        type: 'border',
        align: 'stretch '
    },
    height: 620,

    style: {
        'backgroundColor': '#909090 !important'
    },

    items: [{
        // xtype: 'panel' implied by default
        title: 'Geo-Africa Administration',
        region: 'west',
        xtype: 'panel',
        //margin: '5 0 0 5',
        width: 200,
        collapsible: true, // make collapsible
        id: 'west-region-container',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'treelist',

            store: {
                root: {
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [{
                        text: 'Options',
                        leaf: true,
                        iconCls: 'fas fa-address-book'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Administration',
                        expanded: true,
                        iconCls: 'far fa-id-badge',
                        children: [{
                            text: 'Configuration',
                            leaf: true,
                            iconCls: 'fas fa-address-card'
                        }, {
                            text: 'User',
                            leaf: true,
                            iconCls: 'fas fa-child'
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'basic-panels'

        // width: '100%'
    }]
```

Which i render on button click like so :

```
  var dash =  Ext.create('widget.newDashboard', {
               renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                hideMode: 'visibility'
             });
              dash.show();
```

How can i assign a route URI to that view in ExtJS (6.2.0)?

Thank you for the great help ?
PS : i tried with

```
routes : {
        'dashboard' : ''

     },
```

or else  `this.redirectTo("dashboard");` But neither works.

Answer (score 1):

The route is similar to firing an event. The end result is a function is called. The hash is passed to the function based on how the route is setup.  You can either call a different function for each hash or you can use the hash, or other parts of the URI to determine what to do.

[Router Documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/guides/application_architecture/router.html) This web page describes how the router is used.  It is a very quick read.

A common way the examples (admin dashboard, coworkee app) do it by having the hash be the xtype for the panel (view) you want to display.

So your main panel extends 'Ext.navigation.View'. Then based on the hash you create a new instance of the view, add it to the main panel and make it the active item.  You can also check to see if the xtype has already been added to the navigation view and just make it the active panel.

[Fiddle showing use of router](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2h94&view/editor) (this is not mine).  Here is a fiddle that shows how to use a router.  I would recommend reading the docs first.  THe sencha docs are actually pretty good and you can learn how to use the Extjs library as it was intended and really speed up your development.

Comment: My Main panel extends `Ext.Container` not `Ext.navigation.View`. Could you provide a concrete exemple setting a route to `Traccar.view.newDashboard` ?

Comment: If you want to show different panels in the main panel then maybe it should extend a panel that allows this, such as the Navigation view or tab panel etc or use the card layout, else you would have to implement the panel switching yourself, which of course go against the tenants of object oriented programming.

Comment: I want by clicking the back button of the browser to return to the previous view. So i don't want new "previous" and "next" buttons to switch views.

Comment: This is how the router works.  It keeps track of history, changes the hash portion of the url.  Did you read the router documentation?  I can't be more clear then the sencha router document.

Comment: Yes i read, still can't figure out the implementation for my classes. I want the views to change not just saving the history.